# How to always round down to the nearest multiple of X in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a grid drawn on a canvas, when the user clicks on the grid, I am drawing a rectangle. I want to always draw the rectangle on top of the grid cell the user is clicking on. So I need to round down to the nearest X, in my case, a multiple of 40.

Some examples ...

```
121 => 120
125 => 120
139 => 120
159 => 120
160 => 160
```

So far I have the rounding working using the following...

```
x = Math.round(x / constants.MAP_CELL_SIZE) * constants.MAP_CELL_SIZE;
```

This **almost** handles the rounding, the only thing I am missing is the rounding down to the nearest multiple of 40, which is held in `constants.MAP_CELL_SIZE`.

Hopefully this makes sense, and someone can lend a hand ... much appreciated!

---

**Update**

It was just as simple as switching from `Math.round` to `Math.floor`.

Comment: To round *down*, use `Math.floor()`. `Math.round()` goes both ways - up or down whichever is closer. Documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

Comment: Yikes! @ŠimeVidas, it was just that easy ... switching from Math.round to Math.floor did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: apologies for misreading your code. assumed it was already Math.floor()

Comment: No problem @Ejay ... I still appreciated the time taken for the suggestion!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To round down, use Math.floor() instead of Math.round(). You can use it like this:

```
var customFloor = function(value, roundTo) {
    return Math.floor(value / roundTo) * roundTo;
}

customFloor(121, constants.MAP_CELL_SIZE); // => 120
customFloor(159, constants.MAP_CELL_SIZE); // => 120
customFloor(160, constants.MAP_CELL_SIZE); // => 160
```

See documentation of [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) on MDN.

Comment: does this operation have a name?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truncate the fractional portion of a number, you can use a bitwise operator on it, which will treat the number as a 32 bit integer.

```
x = x | 0;
```

Keep in mind this has different behaviour than `Math.round()`, which will round correctly with negative numbers.

Comment: Note that with _huge_ numbers that this will not yield expected results, nor is it significantly faster overall (max 10% in Javascript).  Otherwise, this is quite a concise way of doing something like this without all of the function "fluff".