# Always round down to multiples of 1000

Tags: javascript

I have to round down any values to multiples of 1000.

Example 1,

```
var myValue = 23452;
Math.round(myValue/1000)*1000; 
23000
```

Example 2,

```
var myValue = 22745;
Math.round(myValue/1000)*1000; 
23000
```

In above cases example 1 is giving expected round down value as **23000**, however example 2, I'm expecting **22000**

how to achieve any values to always round down to multiples to 1000.
more examples,

```
if 6700 then 6000
if 17500 then 17000
if 356242 then 350000
if 600 then 0
```

Comment: [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) does not have any parameter to choose the algorithm. You need an entirely different function: [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to always round down to the nearest multiple of X in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728893/how-to-always-round-down-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-x-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enter the Modulus operator.

```
var myValue = 22745;
var remainder = myValue % 1000; //745
var myRoundedValue = myValue - remainder; //22000
```